# Why I cannot create a folder that does not exist (simple-mtpfs mounted filesystem)?

Tags: fuse, mkdir, mtp

I am mounting my USB-connected phone using `simple-mtpfs`, and it is shown as `fuse.simple-mtpfs` when I do `df`.

I then switch to a folder on the external SDCARD of the phone, and try to create a folder `.thumb`. I get

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '.thumb': Invalid argument
```

despite the fact that the folder does not exist, and that I can create other folders. Look:

```
$> ls -la
total 1294
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato   2118 May 11  2019 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 224912 May 11  2019 vista-pao_de_acucar-040803-2776a.jpg
$> mkdir .thum
$> mkdir .thumb1
$> mkdir .thumb
mkdir: cannot create directory '.thumb': Invalid argument
$> ls -la .th*
.thum:
total 0
.thumb1:
total 0
$> rmdir .thum
$> rmdir .thumb1
$> rmdir .thumb
rmdir: failed to remove '.thumb': No such file or directory
$> mkdir .thumb
mkdir: cannot create directory '.thumb': Invalid argument
$> ls -la
total 1294
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato   2118 May 11  2019 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 224912 May 11  2019 vista-pao_de_acucar-040803-2776a.jpg
$> mkdir .thumb1
$> mkdir .thum
$> ls -la
total 1294
drwxrwxr-x 2 gato gato      0 Dec 31  1969 .thum/
drwxrwxr-x 2 gato gato      0 Dec 31  1969 .thumb1/
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato   2118 May 11  2019 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 224912 May 11  2019 vista-pao_de_acucar-040803-2776a.jpg
$> rmdir .thumb1
$> rmdir .thum
$> ls -la
total 1294
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato   2118 May 11  2019 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 gato gato 224912 May 11  2019 vista-pao_de_acucar-040803-2776a.jpg
$> mkdir .thumb
mkdir: cannot create directory '.thumb': Invalid argument
$>
```

Before this, I was trying `rsync` without success.

Any clues?

Comment: It may be some sort of reserved filename? Or there may already exist a `.thumb` directory that is hidden from you by the FS layer for whatever reason. Can you create a _file_ called `something.thumb`?

Comment: Yes, I can create a file `.thumb` with `touch`, the folder `1.thumb`, but I cannot create the folder `.thumb`. It seems I can do everything except creating the folder `.thumb`.

Comment: Actually, I cannot create the `.thumb` folder in the folder I was working on (say, `xyz`). But if I go to the parent folder with a `cd ..`, then I can create it. So only the `xyz/.thumb` folder cannot be created. It seems there is some kind of problem with the filesystem?

Comment: Is `xyz` on another filesystem?

Comment: No. Both are inside the external sd card.